# As a library developer, how to prevent users from using an object across multiple Threads/Processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am building a library for Python and noticed that one of my users was using the objects incorrectly, by sharing it between 2 Processes.

So, I wanted to bake in a way to prevent the user from doing that.

One way would be to add a "check" before every method call, using a decorator, but that adds a bit of overhead on each method call.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading


def is_parent():
    return (
        multiprocessing.current_process().name == "MainProcess"
        and threading.current_thread() == threading.main_thread()
    )


def process_unsafe(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not is_parent():
            raise RuntimeError("Not allowed!")
        fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class NonProcessSafe:
    @process_unsafe
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @process_unsafe
    def bar(self):
        pass


nps = NonProcessSafe()

nps.foo()
nps.bar()


def child():
    # complains
    nps.foo()


p = multiprocessing.Process(target=child)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Definitely mention it in the documentation. I doubt there's a good way to close all the loopholes with code, so the only winning game might be not to play.

Comment: Please give details _why_ it is incorrect usage to share these objects between processes or threads. What bad effects will happen if you share? (Sharing between processes - how? Via shared memory?)

Comment: Apparently, the documentation doesn't seem to be enough of a barrier...
https://zproc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/introduction.html#something-to-keep-in-mind

Comment: I have it written over all the objects' API docs too, but python makes it easy to get this wrong :(

Comment: @digitalarbeiter Okay will plan to write a detailed page on this.

Answer (score 0):

As @timgeb mentioned in the comments, there's probably no way to close all the loopholes. Furthermore I'm not sure I fully understand your problem and process/thread/state sharing model...

Anyway, here's an Ansatz that might get you somewhere, at least with regards to processes (in the Unix/Linux sense):

```
import os

class State:

    def __init__(self):
        self._pid = os.getpid()
        self._state = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if os.getpid() != self._pid:
            raise RuntimeError("this process must not change state")
        self._state[key] = value
```

The `State` instance remembers the ID of the process that created it, and can then check against that ID in all (relevant) methods. This will of course require the State be created by its "owner" process, in which case it is invisible to any parent or sibling process anyway, and visible only to itself and its children.

For threads, use `threading.get_ident()` instead of `os.getpid()`.

If it is always the "main" process that creates the state and then forks worker children, instead you could (in the main process) temporarily mark the state as read-only, fork the worker child so it gets a read-only copy, and then in the main process switch state back to read-write:

```
class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self._read_only = False
        self._state = {}
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self._read_only:
            raise RuntimeError("read only!")
        self._state[key] = value
```

In main process:

```
def new_worker(fct):
    state = State()
    state._read_only = True
    pid = os.fork()  # or whatever you use to create a new process
    if pid:
        fct()  # state is _read-only=True here in child process
    else:
        state._read_only = False
        state_list.append((pid, state))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to understand the problem and my library, but this doesn't also apply to other classes like Context and Process. I still have to make the `if os.getpid() != self._pid:` check, which will add a overhead, as I mentioned in the question.

It is better than the "MainProcess" thing I'm doing..

Comment: > I'm not sure I fully understand your problem and process/thread/state sharing model --
It lets you do shared state parallelism without actually having shared memory objects, by operator overloading and message passing :)

Comment: Okay, but what's the scenario where one process tries to use objects from another process? I can think of two scenarios: a) it's a shared object, and your __setitem__/message passing takes care of it, and b) the object was created in the main/parent process and inherited into all worker/children as local copies (via the copy on write mechanism of the operating system), so changes stay local to each child process. Is that the issue?

Comment: For the `State` object specifically, the issue is that the message passing (all dict methods) depend on a few non-thread-safe objects, ZMQ Context, Sockets, an "identity" that helps the framework separate different clients etc. For others, like `Context`, there are the `Process` objects which are neither serialize-able nor thread-safe. Basically, the whole architecture is designed to eliminate the need for shared objects, and I want to have a way to prevent the user from doing it.

Comment: And yes, the framework already creates new objects with proper connections for the child processes and provides them. Unfortunately, that doesn't prevent the user from shooting themselves in the foot. Kinda like how a beginner might try to share a socket between 2 processes.

Comment: I did %timeit the approach we have currently, but the `os.getpid()` call adds an overhead of `~500ns`. I don't know if I should accept this..